# Seaborn displot - Can the y axis be set to show density when plot has histogram and KDE

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Hi I am new to using Jupyter notebooks, python, matplotlib, pandas & seaborn. I am trying to plot a density plot using the displot function in seaborn. I want to be able to see the histogram aswell but instead of "count" on the y axis I want to see the density.
The old distplot function automatically shows density I just don't know how to set it with the new displot. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Note that in this case, `sns.histplot(..., kde=True, stat='density')` is the replacement of the old `sns.distplot()`.  `displot()` is an associated figure-level function and creates a grid of subplots.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to answer my own question...
stat="density"
example:
sns.displot(data=df_under_100, x="processingtime_wks", stat="density", binwidth=5, binrange=(0.0, 100.0), kde=True)